# how to change Jscolor to remove hex

Tags: javascript, html, jscolor

Hey if anybody knows http://jscolor.com/    I'm trying to have it in html without showing the hex code. I can't find where to hide the text in the long js file, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{valueElement:null}`. Example:

```
<button
class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}">
</button>
```

More info:
http://jscolor.com/examples/#example-custom-look